# CSS3 Keyframe Animations: End and stay on the last frame

Tags: javascript, css, animation, less

I've run into some difficulty trying to play a CSS3 keyframe animation and have the relevant element stick at the last frame after the animation has completed. To my understanding, the property that I have to set for this to work should be animation-fill-mode, which should have the value of forwards; this doesn't do anything.

```
.animatedSprite { 
    .animation-name: sprite;
    .animation-duration: .5s;
    .animation-iteration-count: 1;
    .animation-direction: normal; 
    .animation-timing-function: steps(3); 
    .animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    //Vendor prefixes... }
```

This will just play the animation once and then go back to the first frame. I found an example of keyframe animations at JSFiddle ( http://jsfiddle.net/simurai/CGmCe/ ), and changing the fill mode to forwards and setting the iteration count to 1 wouldn't do anything there, either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

`animation-fill-mode:forwards` is the correct property to use. Is does not *seem* to work because the sprite image background has a default [`background-repeat:repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-repeat), so the *last* frame you think you are seeing is actually the *first* frame of the repeated background image.

If you set

```
background: url("http://files.simurai.com/misc/sprite.png") no-repeat

animation: play .8s steps(10) forwards;

@keyframes play {
    from { background-position:    0px; }
    to { background-position: -500px; }
}
```

and run the demo the final frame is now blank - so `forwards` is doing what it should do. The second part of the solution is to change the final `to` and `steps` CSS properties to position the background correctly. So we really need the background to stop at `-450px` and use `9` steps.

```
-webkit-animation: play .8s steps(9) forwards;

@keyframes play {
    from { background-position: 0; }
    to { background-position: -450px; }
}
```

[**See demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/0q25gq7k/) - I only fixed the Chrome properties. Also here is the sample image in case the original disappears.

[image: Waving sprite]

```css
.hi {
    width: 50px;
    height: 72px;
    background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilKfd.png") no-repeat;
    
    -webkit-animation: play .8s steps(9) forwards;
       -moz-animation: play .8s steps(10) infinite;
        -ms-animation: play .8s steps(10) infinite;
         -o-animation: play .8s steps(10) infinite;
            animation: play .8s steps(9) forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes play {
   from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -450px; }
}

@-moz-keyframes play {
   from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -500px; }
}

@-ms-keyframes play {
   from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -500px; }
}

@-o-keyframes play {
   from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -500px; }
}

@keyframes play {
   from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -450px; }
}
```

```html
<div class="hi"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Neil - I have updated and embedded the demo now

Comment: Perfect example @andyb. Thank you

Comment: Thanks, the forwards property helps but in my case it still wasn't enough, so I had to shorten the width by the width of the last frame and then decrease the steps number by one

Answer (score 2):

Change 'infinite' to '1' in the css, this fixes it for me

Comment: Hey Adam, this returns it to the first frame for me (After additionally adding the fill-mode: forwards property), as opposed to stopping on the last.

Answer (score 0):

just add

```
animation: mymove .8s forwards;
```

here 'mymove' is name of my keyframe

example:

```
<html>
<head>
<style> 
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
 animation: mymove .8s forwards;
}

@keyframes mymove {
  from {top: 0px;}
  to {top: 200px;}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>The @keyframes Rule</h1>

<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

The following code will make the transition stay on the last frame:

```
-webkit-timing-function:ease;
-webkit-iteration-count:1;
```

Comment: This is wrong, it's `forwards`, not the iteration count. If you do iteration at 1, at the end of the last frame it will revert back.